# Tracking pixel cross domain, ASP.NET, jQuery, AJAX

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, json, tracking

I am have page tracking / tracking pixel page that is currently using $.post(PAIRS-DATA) to post the information being collected in the JavaScript back to the server.  Then finally loads as a tracking pixel.

```
        finally
        {
            //tracking pixel
            Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
            byte[] buffer = pix.BinaryData;
            int len = buffer.Length;
            Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);

        }
```

The problem is, $.post(PAIRS-DATA) is canceled in Chrome, because it's cross domain. So I tried

```
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: false,
            processData: false,
            crossDomain: true,                
            url: "URL",
            data: dataPairs
        });
```

This take care of the cross domain issue but I now get "**Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type image/gif:**"

How can I fix this?  is there something wrong with the $.ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax call fails because JSONP requires that the server actually send back JSONP (i.e. JSON + a wrapper).

If you have to gather data with JS before you can load the image, you could try passing the needed data in the query string for the image.

Example:

`$(document).append('<img src="http://host.com/path/to/image?' + formatDataAsQueryString());`

Comment: So, I remove the tracking  Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
            byte[] buffer = pix.BinaryData;
            int len = buffer.Length;
            Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);  and just pass back an image?  Wouldn't that slow things down?